# How do I collect Twitter lists_memberships from several users in R?

Tags: r, list, twitter, rtweet

I would like to get the names of the lists a Twitter user is a member of. I can do this one by one:

```
nytimes <- lists_memberships("nytimes", n = 1000, cursor = "-1", filter_to_owned_lists = FALSE, 
parse = TRUE, token = NULL)
```

But I'd like to do this for **several users simultaneously**. I've tried the following so far:

```
library(rtweet)
outliers <- c("dpontarlier","0liviahouseman", "andreavocado", "imagine_garden", "fashionforgood")
lists_outliers <- lapply(outliers, lists_memberships)
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error message:

> Warning: 34 - Sorry, that page does not exist.

I've searched for the error and other options on how to collect the list memberships for several users but couldn't find anything yet. Can someone help?